# SymPy does not recognize equal values

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

Simple calculations in SymPy quickly create unwieldy results like the three `should_be` values below.
Comparisons to the correct values give `False` (although `math.isclose` gives `True`).

```
from sympy import sqrt
phi = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2
should_be_phi = -(1/2 + sqrt(5)/2)**2 + (1/2 + sqrt(5)/2)**3
should_be_half = -sqrt(5)/8 + 1/8 + (1/2 + sqrt(5)/2)**2/4
should_be_one = -sqrt(5)/4 + 1/4 + (1/2 + sqrt(5)/2)**2/2
print(should_be_phi == phi, should_be_half == 1/2, should_be_one == 1)
```

These are the same formulas formatted by Wolfram Alpha:
phi: [image]     
half: [image]     
one: [image]
`should_be_phi` was created as `phi**3 - phi**2` btw.

Currently I always copy these monstrosities to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) to get decent formulas and to remove duplicates.

Do you also get `False` for each comparison? I use Python 3.6.8 and SymPy 1.4.

Is there a way do do symbolic calculations in Python that actually works?
SymPy seems to be unable to do the things it is supposedly made for.

Comment: Check out documentation on https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html :-). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that what you want is for those expressions to be simplified so just use the `simplify` function:

```
In [6]: from sympy import *

In [7]: phi = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2

In [8]: should_be_phi = -(S(1)/2 + sqrt(5)/2)**2 + (S(1)/2 + sqrt(5)/2)**3

In [9]: should_be_phi
Out[9]: 
          2           3
  ⎛1   √5⎞    ⎛1   √5⎞ 
- ⎜─ + ──⎟  + ⎜─ + ──⎟ 
  ⎝2   2 ⎠    ⎝2   2 ⎠ 

In [10]: simplify(should_be_phi)
Out[10]: 
1   √5
─ + ──
2   2
```

Note that you should use `S(1)/2` rather than `1/2` which gives a float.

If you want to compare expressions then the obvious way would be to use `==` but that is for "structural equality" in SymPy. What that means is that `expr1 == expr2` will give `True` only when the expressions are in the exact same form. If you want to test for mathematical equality then you should use `Eq(lhs, rhs)` or `simplify(lhs-rhs)`:

```
In [11]: should_be_phi == phi    # Expressions are not in the same form
Out[11]: False

In [12]: Eq(should_be_phi, phi)
Out[12]: True

In [13]: simplify(should_be_phi - phi)
Out[13]: 0
```

> Is there a way do do symbolic calculations in Python that actually works?
>   SymPy seems to be unable to do the things it is supposedly made for.

Unlike Wolfram Alpha, SymPy is not designed to be usable or understandable to someone who has not read any of the documentation. Your questions above would be answered if you had read the first few pages of the SymPy tutorial:
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html#tutorial

Comment: Oops... I was misled by the fact that comparisons like `sqrt(5)**2 == 5`, `phi**0 == 1` or `phi**0 + phi**0 == sqrt(2)**2` actually do give `True`.